# How to combine 3 MySQL table inserts

Tags: php, mysql, multiple-tables

So, I'm creating a user system in php. And of course users need to be inserted in my MySQL table. Now, I've got three tables that need to be filled:
- emails 
---- id, email, subscriber
- addresses 
---- id, street, street_number, zip_code, city, country, phone, btw_number, company
- users 
---- id, username, password, salt, surname, name, joined, email_id, permissions_id, address_id, address_2_id

I could insert the email query, then select it's ID (auto inc) as id1. After that INSERT address and SELECT the id (auto inc) and then combine those 2 to INSERT in the users table. But is there a more quicker way so that I don't have to select the id each time after I've inserted the data?

Comment: If users have zero or more addresses, and zero or more emails, then the emails and addresses tables will need a foreign key back to the users table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a mysql function for that.
You can do the First user-insert and After that you can use LAST_INSERT_ID().
that Seems to be exactly what you need. 
For More informations you can go [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/getting-unique-id.html)

And [here](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_insert_lastid.asp) you got some code examples